# triggering multiples functions with react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to trigger a function every time a different radio button is clicked in my form.  This is the form:

```
           <FormControl>
            <RadioGroup
                row
                aria-labelledby="demo-row-radio-buttons-group-label"
                name="row-radio-buttons-group"
                value = {selectionValue}
                onChange={handleSelection}
            >
                <FormLabel id="demo-radio-buttons-group-label">Price Selection</FormLabel>
                    <FormControlLabel id="standard" value="standard" control={<Radio />} label="standard" />
                    <FormControlLabel id="premium" value="premium" control={<Radio />} label="premium" />
                    <FormControlLabel id="excelium" value="excelium" control={<Radio />} label="excelium" />
            </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
```

and it triggers this onChange={handlefunction} which works and calls serviceCalc():

```
const [selectionValue, setSelectionValue] = useState("")

const handleSelection = (event : any) => {
    setSelectionValue(event.target.value);
    serviceCalc()
}
```

my problem is when I get to serviceCalc() the function prints my console.log and thats it. how can I get standard(), premium() and excelium() to go trough?

```
const serviceCalc = () => {

    console.log("service calc")

    const standard1 = (document.getElementById("standard") as HTMLInputElement);
    const premium1 = (document.getElementById("premium") as HTMLInputElement);
    const excelium1 = (document.getElementById("excelium") as HTMLInputElement);

    
    if (standard1.checked){                      
        standard();
    }
else if (premium1.checked) {             
        premium();
    }
    else if (excelium1.checked) {          
        excelium();
    }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If any of them were undefined you would get a TypeError, have you checked for that? If there is no error than either `checked` does not exist on the objects or it is false

Comment: I dont have a TypeError, it probably doesnt exists or it is false but im not sure how to fix that @about14sheep

Comment: either use a debugger or just console log `standard1` or `standard1.checked` to see

Answer (score 1):

The `id` you're passing to `<FormControlLabel id="someId"/>` component, **is NOT** the `id` of the `<input>` HTML element **but** the `id` of its `<label>` element.

So when you check for `document.getElementById("someId").checked` you always get `undefined` and then you'll never go through your `if - else` checks.

Comment: Thank for your reply! do you know how I could do something like this? `((document.getElementById("standard") as HTMLLabelElement).checked)` since it says `Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLLabelElement'`

Comment: `<label>` HTML element has no `checked` property, so you can't access it (as Typescript says).

What you could do is to pass the selected value of the Radio button as an argument to `serviceCalc()` function, so in that function you receive a value to decide which function to execute